# Very high latency with Verizon DSL

Tags: networking, isp, latency

At any time in a given day, my ping could be anywhere from 60ms (already too high) to over 1000ms. I've contacted Verizon support numerous times, but it doesn't seem anyone in the tech support center seems to know the difference between bandwidth and latency. A tech support guy is coming out to fix a cable for the second time in two weeks, but I'd like to get a bit more insight on what the community thinks is the real problem. I've done a bit of researching, and it looks as if I'm on a very congested "node", or "server". Is it possible to request to being switched to a different node? I have also posted a `tracert` to `www.google.com` below, which is actually taken on a pretty good day.

```
1     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  VERIZONDRIVE [192.168.1.1]
2    46 ms    45 ms    44 ms  10.29.11.1
3    48 ms    46 ms    48 ms  P0-2.SCTNPA-LCR-02.verizon-gni.net [130.81.44.18]
4    50 ms    51 ms    52 ms  G13-0-0.SCTNPA-LCR-01.verizon-gni.net [130.81.151.34]
5    49 ms    50 ms    50 ms  xe-4-1-8-0.NWRK-BB-RTR1.verizon-gni.net [130.81.209.194]
6    60 ms    63 ms    61 ms  0.xe-6-1-1.XT1.NYC4.ALTER.NET [152.63.10.57]
7    66 ms    63 ms    64 ms  TenGigE0-6-0-0.GW8.NYC4.ALTER.NET [152.63.22.41]
8    75 ms    77 ms    79 ms  google-gw.customer.alter.net [152.179.72.62]
9   153 ms    63 ms    63 ms  209.85.255.68
10    63 ms    63 ms    64 ms  209.85.252.242
11    63 ms    61 ms    62 ms  209.85.249.11
12    67 ms   104 ms    64 ms  72.14.236.153
13    63 ms    61 ms    63 ms  72.14.238.253
14    65 ms    64 ms    66 ms  iad23s08-in-f20.1e100.net [74.125.228.116]
```

EDIT: Added WinMTR data. This is much more accurate, as I left it go all day with no one using the network.

```
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|                                      WinMTR statistics                                     |
|                       Host              -   %  | Sent  | Recv  | Best | Avrg | Wrst | Last |
|------------------------------------------------|-------|-------|------|------|------|------|
|                            VERIZONDRIVE -    1 | 37465 | 37414 |    1 |    1 |  102 |    1 |
|                              10.29.11.1 -    0 | 37660 | 37660 |   43 |   46 | 1053 |   46 |
|     P15-2.SCTNPA-LCR-01.verizon-gni.net -    0 | 37660 | 37660 |   44 |   47 | 1076 |   47 |
| xe-4-1-8-0.NWRK-BB-RTR1.verizon-gni.net -    1 | 37656 | 37655 |   48 |   59 | 1056 |   52 |
|           0.so-6-0-3.XT1.NYC4.ALTER.NET -    1 | 37618 | 37607 |   57 |   74 | 1125 |   59 |
|       TenGigE0-4-0-0.GW8.NYC4.ALTER.NET -    1 | 37628 | 37620 |   56 |   63 | 1061 |   60 |
|            google-gw.customer.alter.net -   20 | 21169 | 17041 |    0 |   76 | 1507 |   67 |
|                           209.85.255.68 -    2 | 35571 | 35045 |   56 |   62 | 1202 |   59 |
|                          209.85.252.242 -    1 | 37636 | 37630 |   57 |   62 |  856 |   62 |
|                           209.85.249.11 -    1 | 37624 | 37615 |   55 |   61 | 1532 |   58 |
|                           72.14.236.153 -    1 | 37613 | 37601 |   56 |   62 | 1188 |   58 |
|                           72.14.238.253 -    1 | 37499 | 37458 |   57 |   61 | 1516 |   62 |
|               iad23s08-in-f19.1e100.net -    1 | 37636 | 37630 |   56 |   60 | 1548 |   59 |
|________________________________________________|_______|_______|______|______|______|______|
```

Comment: As to whether you can change nodes, no one here can tell you. Contact Verizon

Comment: Are you on wireless? By far the #1 cause of random latency jumps I have seen is wifi.

Comment: Yes...I am on wifi. At the time I have no way of getting a network cable to my machine. Is there a way to see if the wifi is the cause before I go ripping into the walls to install ethernet jacks?

Comment: @cmorse On second thought, my PC used to be wired into the router and I still had issues, so I doubt wifi is the main problem.

Comment: Get WinMTR (for Windows) or MTR (for Linux or other OS's) and use it like "traceroute".  If you leave it running a while it will provide information as to where the problem is coming in, but providing min, avg and max latency and also packet loss.

Comment: We'd really need to see a traceroute that demonstrates the problem. But it looks like it's load on your actual DSL line. Are you sure all your filters are in place?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz They should all be in place, maybe one is faulty. The tracert does demonstrate the problem, just not as bad as it can get. 60ms is still too high for what I do.

Comment: @Novicode: Double-check things like alarm systems, satellite TV receivers, and the like -- things you forget are connected to the phone line. Maybe you added or moved something.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I'll give everything a double check, if the service guy has phone filters, I'll replace all the old ones, too. I also added that WinMTR data that really shows my problem, especially with the worst pings.

Comment: How many miles are you from Scranton, PA?

Comment: For DSL 60ms isn't really unreasonable.  Unfortunately, this is one of those occasions where you get what you pay for.  Just for grins and giggles I ran a tracert to 8.8.8.8 from my office and I hit 54ms.  And just so you have a frame of reference, I am on Time Warner Business Class direct connect Fiber @ 100Mbps.  using a single destination isn't a good metric to isolate your issue to your circuit.  Internet routes change constantly at the provider level so you really should test to your destination that you are having issues with and go from there.  DSL might not meet your needs.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz About 30 by road

Comment: @MikeAWood DSL is my only option, and Verizon is the only ISP that services the area with DSL. I can understand how it would be with limited speed, but there is no reason for it to spike to over 1000ms

Comment: @Novicode, agreed, 1000ms is really high, but there are plenty of reasons your connection might do that.    The issues with this come in where your router wouldn't be able to keep up with the traffic load.  There is a huge difference between a commercial grade firewall and a home firewall WRT this.  When you notice this happening again, take a good look at attached devices on your router, start from there and work backwards. remove the router and connect to the modem directly.  if the problem remains, then bug VZ, otherwise check your network closely and go from there..

Comment: @MikeAWood The modem and router are combined, so I can't just disconnect the router. You said the firewall might be slowing traffic down? Is it worth trying to disable it, my computer has AVG Internet Security with a strong firewall, and I think I might have had it disabled before.

Comment: If it is the same device and provided by Verizon, it would seem like a verizon issue and something you should follow up with them on.  But I would exhaust all local options first and make sure someone/something on your network isn't causing your problems.  If you log into the router, is there a log page that shows any attacks/events that mighe help explain the lag?